# Custom exception not caught in calling method

Tags: java, spring, exception

I have a custom exception that I throw in a class that is not caught in another class.

I don't know what's wrong here :

Class MailService.java

```
@Async
public void sendMail(String to, String subject) throws EmailNotSentException {
    throw new EmailNotSentException();
}
```

Class MailResource.java

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/mails-envoyes",
        method = RequestMethod.POST,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@Timed
public ResponseEntity<MailEnvoye> createMailEnvoye(@RequestBody MailEnvoye mailEnvoye, HttpServletRequest request) throws URISyntaxException {
    try{
        mailService.sendMail(to, "subject");
    }catch (EmailNotSentException e){
        log.debug(e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
}
```

Exception

```
public class EmailNotSentException extends MessagingException {

    public EmailNotSentException() {
        super();
    }
    public EmailNotSentException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }

    public EmailNotSentException(String message, Exception e) {
        super(message, e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you are running in debug?

Comment: How are you sure that the other exceptions are also detected?

Comment: Have you tried catching Exception, to be sure anything is thrown at all ?

Comment: @Async methods are executed in new thread so you can not catch exceptions by catch clause. Please read following Spring docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#scheduling-annotation-support-exception

Comment: Same issue with Exception. I have an error in log console but it is not caught in the try catch.     20/03/2019 - 09:21 [ERROR] com.myapp.rh.aop.logging.LoggingAspect - Exception in com.myapp.rh.service.MailService.sendMail() with cause = null and exception {}
java.lang.Exception: null
 at com.myapp.rh.service.MailService.sendMail(MailService.java:739)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is probably the `@Async` annotation (I'm assuming this code runs with Spring) ... as it says on the tin, it run it asynchronously, which means that it will run in a different thread, so the calling method will never receive the Exception.

If you want to handle the exception in the way you have in your code, just remove the `@Async` annotation.

There are a few articles around which explain how to catch an exception from an async method (google is your friend), and make it available so something else can deal with it, but it's always asynchronously.